# How to change query from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT 
    @Principal= IIF(optionfieldvalue='', NULL, CAST(optionfieldvalue as decimal(38, 18)))
FROM 
    @DATA 
WHERE 
    TemplateFieldId = 47
```

This query was written in SQL Server 2012. Now I want to change that to SQL Server 2008 R2.

can any one help who to convert that code

Comment: use `CASE` instead of `IIF`

Comment: Have you tried just running it in 2008? what error message do you get when you do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the `IIF` which is new in SQL Server **2012**:

```
SELECT 
    @Principal = CASE 
                   WHEN optionfieldvalue = '' 
                      THEN CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(38,18))
                      ELSE CAST(optionfieldvalue AS DECIMAL(38, 18))
                 END
FROM 
    @DATA 
WHERE 
    TemplateFieldId = 47
```